# How to merge 2 JSON objects in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to merge 2 JSON objects in Azure Logic App. Is that possible? Properties of one object is known but the other one is not.

Comment: Have you tried creating it? Could you elaborate more by providing your logic app view?

Answer (score 0):

There are different options available to merge JOSN objects in Logic App.

1. [Logic App - Compose Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) Very easy to implement.
2. [Logic App - Inline Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code?tabs=consumption) You can write JavaScript code.